# Error no capturado

Tags: c#, sql-server, try-catch

Buenos dias desde Venezuela grupo. Tengo la siguiente rutina en la capa Datos:

```
DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

public DataTable Look(string SQL)
    {
        try
        {
            cmd.Connection = nConn.OpenConn();
            cmd.CommandText = SQL;
            Read = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            tbl.Load(Read);
            Read.Close();
            nConn.CloseConn();
            return tbl;
        }
        catch(SqlException ex)
        {
            nConn.CloseConn();
            return tbl;
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

En la linea 'tbl.Load(Read)' me arroja el error:

> System.Data.ConstraintException: No se pudieron habilitar las
>   restricciones. Una o varias filas contienen valores que infringen las
>   restricciones NON-NULL, UNIQUE o FOREIGN-KEY

1.- A que puede deberse que el try no capture el error?
2.- El comando SQL se ejecuta correctamente en SQL Server, pero en la rutina da error, el SQL es simple:

```
SELECT * FROM tblTownMaster WHERE Wx_Tmst_Town_Code = '267'
```

Agradezco cualquier idea al respecto.

Comment: El catch es únicamente para "SqlException", no para "ConstraintException"

Answer (score 1):

> A que puede deberse que el try no capture el error
>   ConstraintException?

No puedes capturar el error puesto que estas únicamente capturando el tipo de error `SqlException`:

```
try
    {
        ...
        ...
    }
    catch(SqlException ex)
    {
        ...
        ...
    }
```

Agrega la captura para el tipo de error `ConstraintException` :

```
try
    {
        ...
        ...
    }
    catch(SqlException ex)
    {
        ...
        ...
    }        
    catch(ConstraintException ex)
    {
        ...
        ...
    }
```

En cuanto a el problema:

> System.Data.ConstraintException: No se pudieron habilitar las
>   restricciones. Una o varias filas contienen valores que infringen las
>   restricciones NON-NULL, UNIQUE o FOREIGN-KEY

Tu tabla tiene definida una columna con una propiedad de identidad establecida, por lo cual no puedes insertar o tener registros duplicados en estos campos.

Si estas realizando únicamente una consulta de los datos verifica que no tenga definido un campo UNIQUE o FOREIGN-KEY con registro duplicado.

Aunque me parece que alguno de tus query trata de realizar una inserción.

Comment: agradezco la aclaratoria. Pero el comando SQL (no se si lo vistes es una consulta) y la tabla no tiene campos unicos ni foreing-key. Solo tiene una clave que es el código, no está relacionada con ninguna otra tabla y todos los campos nvarchar permiten nulos. Por eso no entiendo el error. Pero gracias por la ayuda

Comment: @MaximilianoGilToro agrega la definición de la tabla tblTownMaster.